# How to open a page in a new tab but don't give it focus?(JSF 2.0)

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

What i want is to open a page in a new tab but don't give focus to the new opened tab. 
So if i click a few times i can open a few tabs.

Just as if i right clicked a link and said open in new tab(I tried that only in chrome and firefox browsers).

Do you know is it possible?

Currently i open new tabs using a form with a button that looks like this:

```
<h:form target="_blank">
         <h:commandButton action="#{mainPageBB.toLink}"/>  
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with many other things which changes the client default behaviour, that's simply not possible by HTML/JS, so JSF as being just a HTML/JS code generator already can't do much for you. It could namely be experienced as intruding and thus result in Bad User Experience, that's also why among others the `target="_blank"` is deprecated. Best what you can do is to add some non-disturbing and helpful remark that the enduser *could* use Ctrl+Click to open the links in new tabs without focusing it.

```html
<p class="note">Consider using Ctrl+Click whenever you want to open links in the background in new tabs.</p>.
```

Still then, this could be a browser-specific/dependent configuration setting, so it may not work that way in all browsers. After all, just provide a bunch of links and let the client decide what to do with it.

Comment: and probably there might be problems with this shortcut on mac

Comment: Yeah probably that's what i should do i will make some kind of message to inform the user. I don't really need that feature, but i was just curious if could it be possible. Thank you!