# Doing a background window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to open a page in a new tab but don't give it focus?(JSF 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161363/how-to-open-a-page-in-a-new-tab-but-dont-give-it-focusjsf-2-0)

I'd like to do a window.open "in the background".  I'd like the browser to stay on the current page.  I found that I could call `self.focus()` right after window.open to go back on the current page.  But the browser does go to the new window first and the user experience isn't ideal.  The code that does this now is

```
    external_window = window.open(url,'_blank');
    self.focus();
    setTimeout("external_window.focus()", 4000);
```

I could have done the window.open in setTimeout.  But the browser would have treated as a pop-up.  The code I have now achieves the goal of staying on the current window to show users a page before going to the new window.  The only problem is the effect of first going to the new window before returning to the current page with `self.focus()`.  Is there any way to do window.open without actual going to that window until I do the `external_window.focus()`?

Comment: self has to be set. maybe `document.focus()`?

Comment: @Topener self is defined, because the original window gets the focus back.  The only issue is preventing the brief focus on the opened window until I `.focus()` in the code.